# How to run with "root" privilaged administrative control on 12.04

Tags: upgrade

The `dpkg --configure -a` is asked by the system when a previous update/upgrade process have not completely performed good, and it must run with `root` privileged administrative user.
Using the `sudo` command we can do a command as `root` user, and `dpkg --configure -a` need be run from root user.
After the  `dpkg --configure -a` command i add all the usual commands (see below) you can run to be sure your system became fully upgraded.

Please also subcribe this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/108601/).

Typing the commands as sudo the system will ask you for a password, please give your user password when requested, you don't see nothing when you type it, then press enter.

So please be sure your system is fully updated/upgraded with no pending packages or errors:

Open a Terminal from the menu Applications → Accessories → Terminal and type:
(if the system ask you a password give your user password, you will not see nothing when you type it, then press enter)

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get --fix-missing install
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Because I a am not familiar with the Ubuntu Terminal commands, could you please give me a more clear interpretation of the above guideliness ?? Specifically should I perform first the above sudo commands or the sudo commands as "root" user??? 
Because I am afraid I will make a mistake again ..
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you having a problem with unsupported repositories?

Answer (score 0):

You should perform the above commands as a user that has the ability to execute the sudo command. "root" user does not need to use the sudo command. "root" user account is disabled by default in Ubuntu for security.

You should just open a terminal and execute the commands one by one using sudo just as they are above. Nothing more, nothing less (except I would probably use `sudo apt-get autoclean` instead of `sudo apt-get clean`).

[Click here for a formal explanation of why you should use sudo and what all that is really about.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

---

As for the dropbox problem, I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/499429/167115) with a solution in the comment section. Backup your dropbox files (if any) and then open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get remove nautilus-dropbox
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If that is not enough, you may need to run this instead:

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus-dropbox
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then, proceed with your upgrade and reinstall dropbox after.

Comment: This is what I get from the first command" Need o know how to proceed"Satellite-A200:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for user: 
Setting up nautilus-dropbox (0.7.1-2) ...

Dropbox is the easiest way to share and store your files online. Want to learn more? Head to http://www.dropbox.com/

Comment: user@user-Satellite-A200:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for user: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
user@user-Satellite-A200:~$ 
How can I do that??

Comment: @user3352216 I have updated the answer with more information pertaining to this specific issue.